Save user position on a HTML file when reloading
For the context, I am working on Python, on a Jupyter Notebook.
Periodically I update values of a HTML file.
To be able to experience live results, I have a Javascript code encapsulated in my Python code, which opens an loads my HTML file on Edge, and periodically automatically reload it, through a function start_auto_refresh (see below), which I call once in my Python code to first load it, and a function stop_auto_refresh to stop refreshing when the Python code finished updating my HTML file values
I have two problems with it:

Every time  it reloads, it loses the user position on the HTML page, despite the code part I wrote
It doesn't stop reloading when calling stop_auto_refresh

Here are:

my start_auto_refresh and stop_auto_refresh function
``` def start_auto_refresh(html_file, interval):
      js_code = f"""
      <script>
      var refreshInterval;
      var refreshWindow = window.open("{html_file}", "_blank");
      function startRefresh() {{
              if (refreshWindow) {{
                  refreshInterval = setInterval(function() {{
                      // Save the scroll position
                      var scrollPos = refreshWindow.scrollY;
                      refreshWindow.localStorage.setItem("scrollPos", scrollPos);
                      // Reload the window
                      refreshWindow.location.href = "{html_file}";
                      // Restore the scroll position after reload
                      refreshWindow.onload = function() {{
                          var savedScrollPos = refreshWindow.localStorage.getItem("scrollPos");
                          if (savedScrollPos !== null) {{
                              refreshWindow.scrollTo(0, parseInt(savedScrollPos, 10));
                          }}
                      }};
                  }}, {interval});
              }}
          }}
      startRefresh();
      </script>
      """
      display.display(display.HTML(js_code))
  def stop_auto_refresh():
      js_code = """
      <script>
      if (refreshInterval) {{
          clearInterval(refreshInterval);
          refreshInterval = null;
      }}
      </script>
      """
      display.display(display.HTML(js_code))




- and my Python code calling for them (for example):

    def run_cdf():
        teams= define_teams()
        [rounds,entering,teams] = define_tournament(teams)
        nbround = rounds[['ID_ROUND']].max().reset_index(name='MAX').iloc[:1].iat[0,1]
        for r in range(1,2):#int(nbround)+1):
            define_HTML_file("games",rounds[rounds['ID_ROUND'] == r])
            path = output_html + "\\round_" +str(r) + ".html"
            path_abs = "CDF_REAL/"+ path.replace("\\","/")
            start_auto_refresh('http://localhost:8888/files/'+ path_abs, 2000)
            [games,teams, rounds] = generate_games(r,rounds, teams)
            define_HTML_file("calculations",rounds[rounds['ID_ROUND'] == r],teams[teams['RANK_FAVOR']> 0].sort_values(by=['RANK_FAVOR'], ascending=[False]))
            path = output_html + "\\round_" +str(r) + ".html"
            path_abs = "CDF_REAL/"+ path.replace("\\","/")
            stop_auto_refresh()        
run_cdf()


Can someone help me with it? Thanks.


probably window.open is seen by the browser as navigating to a new page (even if it's the same url) ... maybe window.reload would keep the scroll position https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload (if I cmd+r reload in a browser it keeps my scroll position)


determine topmost element in viewport,
store globally or cache... or w/e really,
update DOM or content... or w/e really,
call the .scrollIntoView(<element>); DOM function and pass in the element reference.

OR
recursive handler functions and event triggers to update data per element when an individual element is in need of an update rather than entire dom refresh.
